# JSF, Hibernate, Spring Security?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, authentication, spring-security

I'm working on a jsf application, i want to user Spring-Secrity to authetificate my users, i'm using hibernate, the need is : 
 - Authentificate users with Spring-Security.
 - The user authetificated is conserved in a session bean.
 - I need a logout method.
 - I need to know exactly the jars to add to my project.
 - In my database, every user have a role, (user or admin).

The problem with the tutorials i've found, is that no information conserved concerning the current user after authentification, and my case, i need realy a currentuser in my session bean.

How can i make this?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [Spring Web Flow primefaces example](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#whatsnew-samples). It demonstrates integration with JSF, provides JSF tag libs to integrate with Spring Security, etc. In terms of being able to access the current user from a session bean, you can use the [SecurityContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d0e1833) to get the current user from anywhere in your application (including a session bean). For example:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .getAuthentication();
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
```